# autosize columns by default in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to set autosize columns by default with AG-Grid and angular framework. so i have used `gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns` with click event and It's work fine. but when i try use `this.autoSizeAll()` with ngOnInit() to set autosize columns by defaulti get this **error Cannot read property 'getAllColumns'**

i don't know what is the best way which i can autosize columns by default without click button?

```
<button (click)="autoSizeAll(false)">Auto-Size All</button>

<ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 900px; height: 700px;"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>



ngOnInit(){
  this.autoSizeAll();
}

autoSizeAll() {

  const allColumnIds = [];
  // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
  this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns().forEach(function(column) {
    allColumnIds.push(column.colId);
  });
  this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds);
}

onGridReady(params) {

  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  this.http
    .get(
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json'
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.rowData = data;
    });
}
}
```

here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5nHel0jTVmFv9unsGfjo?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the function before it even has initialized the `gridColumnApi`. Try to call `this.autoSizeAll()` in the `onGridReady` function after you have initialized `this.gridColumnApi`.

```
onGridReady(params) {

  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  this.autoSizeAll();  // do your autosizing here
  this.http
    .get(
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json'
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.rowData = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: The error already gone thanks. but the column width still not autosized by default unless i click the button!

Comment: I think I solved this problem by calling this function with a timeout of about 400 ms. Maybe try: `setTimeout(()=>this.autoSizeAll(), 400)`

Comment: Great! now It Work fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can used ag-grid method  onGridReady(event). This method is call when ag-grid is ready to used.

Comment: I'm working on ag-grid but on Vue. Upon seeing this answer, I became aware that params.columnApi is mispelled on the codes I'm working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found is by using the `modelUpdated` event:

```
<ag-grid-angular
   style="width: 900px; height: 700px;"
   class="ag-theme-balham"
   [rowData]="rowData"
   [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
   [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
   (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
   (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
   (modelUpdated)="onModelUpdated()">
</ag-grid-angular>

onModelUpdated() {
  this.autoSizeAll();
}
```